# Selecting maximum column and row id

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

Is there a way to tell MySQL that while making something like this

```
SELECT id, MAX(seq) FROM t1 GROUP BY ident;
```

I can also get the id value?  I know I shouldn't be using `id` if it's not in a group by but I feel like its strange to make a multi pass to get the row ids with the maximum seq field when it already passed it. So what is the most effective way to do this?  `id` is the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mabye:

```
SELECT MAX(a.seq), (SELECT id FROM t1 as b where b.ident=a.ident AND MAX(a.seq) = b.seq LIMIT 1) as id FROM t1 AS a GROUP BY a.ident;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ba5e/1)

Comment: This is exactly what i've been looking for. It calculates the current state on a 350 000 row table in 8 seconds. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aivar thanks ! well above my SQL pay scale, put me in the right ball-park to get my job done!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ident, MAX(seq) seq
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY ident
        ) b ON a.ident = b.ident AND
                a.seq = b.seq
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using self-join:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM MyTable t1
  JOIN
      (SELECT ident, MAX(seq) AS MAX_Seq 
         FROM MyTable 
        GROUP BY ident
      ) t2
    ON t1.seq = t2.MAX_Seq
   AND t1.ident = t2.ident
```

#### See [this sample SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fedc8/2)

Answer (score 0):

What is seq exactly ?

I guess you can also order your results ?

```
SELECT id FROM t1 GROUP BY ident ORDER BY seq DESC
```

Regarding to the others answer, seq is in another table ?